# parameters error in azure ML designer in evaluation metrics in regression model

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I developed a designer to implement regression models in azure machine learning studio. I have taken the data set pill and then split the data set into train and test in prescribed manner. When I am trying to implement the evaluation metrics and run the pipeline, it was showing a warning and error in the moment I called the dataset for the operation. I am bit confused, with the same implementation, when i tried to run with linear regression and it worked as shown in the image. If the same approach is used to implement logistic regression it was showing some warning and error in building the evaluation metrics.

[image]

the above success is in linear regression. When it comes to logistic regression it was showing the warning and error in pipeline.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a sample pipeline with designer with mathematical format.

[image]

We need to create a compute instance.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Assign the compute instance and click on create

[image]

Now the import data warning will be removed. In the same manner, we will be getting similar error in other pills too.

[image]

[image]

Create a mathematical format. If not needed for your case, try to remove that math operation and give the remaining.

[image]

Assign the column set. Select any option according to the requirement.

[image]

Finally, we can find the pills which have no warning or error.

Comment: I recognized that creating the compute instance or cluster is the missing operation from my end. it worked for me now.